# Why does the GET method on asp.net Web API return IQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, iqueryable

In asp.net Web Api2, when you create an async web api controller for a model with entity framework, by default the first method in the new controller is like this:

```
 public IQueryable<MyModel> GetMyModel()
 {
     return db.MyModel;
 }
```

The JSON output from this method is just an array of all of the `MyModel` entries. Meanwhile, all of the other methods for POST,PUT,GET(int id), and DELETE are marked as `async` and return `Task<IHttpActionResult>`. Why isn't the first GET method in the same style, something like this:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMyModel()
 {
     return Ok(await db.MyModel.ToArrayAsync());
 }
```

I've tried this, and it produces identical JSON output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Web API will materialize the result anyway, so the minimum code required is generated.

By calling `ToArrayAsync()` you're essentially doing unnecessary work, that will be done for you later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is IQuerable because API caller can pass filter and that will be added to your dBset so you will get filtered data. 
I will give one example. Consider your MyModal have 3 properties Id, Name, Deleted. If your client application required All rows, Only Non-deleted rows then you have to create two two separate Actions for this. But using IQuerable you can reduce it.

1. For all rows: {host}/api/MyModal
2. For Non-deleted rows: {host}/api/MyModal?$filter(Deleted eq false)

And may more filters like top, skip, lineCount. Even you can do pagination with IQureable.
And Web API will work like Async so need to write explicitly Async.