# .NET Web API IQueryable vs ToList/ToListAsync approaches

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have been dealing with a question about .NET Web API and IQueryable. I have an unit of work object injected via dependency injection in a simple controller in my .NET Web API application. As far as I know, it's possible return an IQueryable in a controller or you can return a List, both cases using for example `.Ok()` and IHttpActionResult as return type.

My doubt is about the difference between, for example, return the IQueryable as [it's done in the default GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924726/why-does-the-get-method-on-asp-net-web-api-return-iqueryable) or call `.ToListAsync()` using await. If I'm not wrong, Web API will materialize the result anyway but in order to be able to materialize it, the data must be loaded in memory, so will need to execute either `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()`, right? How does it choose which method or approach should use to instantiate the data in memory?

```
 public IQueryable<MyModel> GetMyModel()
 {
     return db.MyModel;
 }
```

This would be an example of IQueryable approach.

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMyModel()
 {
     return Ok(await db.MyModel.ToListAsync());
 }
```

This would be an example of .ToListAsync/ToList approach.

Thanks

Comment: I believe the biggest difference is in "how" the data is loaded into memory.  E.g. one at a time with each being disposed or the entire collection at once.

Comment: first of all your api should limit the response, if you are working vs a collection of elements, you should provide pagination to the consumer of your api. Consumers should not expect to load a million records on the fly. Now the IQueryable is executed on the database side, not in memory, once you materialize the collection with a ToList or inside the Ok method you have it in memory, so again, be aware you need to restrict the number of elements you return

Answer (score 0):

When the IQueryable is executed, the result set is treated like an IEnumerable when its materialized.  This in theory is loading each record from the database into memory one at time before sending it off and disposing of it.  By calling either .ToList() or .ToListAsync().  It is saying: Load ALL of my results into a large in memory object and then return that.

It's not terrible but you're prematurely materializing the collection and forcing it into memory in it's entirety.

Comment: You will see a difference in your memory usage if you load a large dataset > 1gb.

Comment: shouldn´t be the same then, if the IQueryable is materialized and treated like an IEnumerable vs calling ```.ToListAsync()```? Both are occupying the same memory amount, right?

Comment: Yes, if your final destination is an in memory list.  If you are sending it somewhere, I believe .ToListAsync() is similar to an IEnumerable in how it builds the list, but the end result is a complete list.  Where as if your endpoint returns IEnumerable then it's loading each item, sending it, and then disposing it instead of building a complete result set in memory first.